# Is it possible to use a boolean expression in this manner?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am currently learning java script and attempting new things, for example I wish to see if I can set a boolean expression to end if it detects a starting number through an ending number.

Or in other terms what I'll want is 3 through 8. 
I will make it clear I am using netbeans IDE.

Within my last else if statement, I want it to end the asking process. I am hoping it is a simple fix, but I can not think of anything that will accomplish this unless I create a lot more else if statements.

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
int[][] table;

boolean stopasking = true;



    while (stopasking = true){

    System.out.println("Let's make a magic Square! How big should it be? ");
    int size = input.nextInt();


    if (size < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("That would violate the laws of mathematics!");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else if (size >= 9)
    {
        System.out.println("That's huge! Please enter a number less than 9.");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else if (size <= 2)
    {
        System.out.println("That would violate the laws of mathematics!");
        System.out.println("");
    }
    else if (size == 3)
    {
        stopasking = false;
    }


    }
```

Comment: You're not learning JavaScript, you're learning Java. The two languages have very little in coming common apart from the name...

Comment: Sorry but that's even what my professor's go out of their way to say what we're going over.

Comment: Let me rephrase: your code is written in Java, not in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the assignmnent operator `=` 
you should use `==` instead

also the condition `size<=2` holds when `size<0` so you can use one `if` for both

```
while(stopasking){
    if (size <= 2) {
        System.out.println("That would violate the laws of mathematics!\n");
    } else if (size >= 9){
       System.out.println("That's huge! Please enter a number less than 9.\n");
    } else if (size == 3){
        stopasking = false;
    }
 }
```

you can use the boolean expression in this way, as condition to exit from a loop. Some would say it is a more elegant solution than `break`.

Comment: Thank you, one small mishap I was actually working on. I did just run it and seen that it wasn't stopping when I was entering 3.

Comment: Understood, but would I be able to get the ending statement to search for an integer of 3 through 8 without making so many other else if statements?

Comment: `while(stopasking==true)` should really be `while(stopasking)`.